# QGIS processing modeler to PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-modeler

I made a processing model in QGIS 3.10 where I calculated a integer value "mycolumn". Within the model, I refactored the "mycolumn" value to Boolean using `mycolumn >= 1`. As I expected, the output layer had a `boolean` field named "mycolumn". I copied the output layer's features to a PostGIS layer with the same setup (Boolean field named "mycolumn"). In the test case, all entries in "mycolumn" were false. When saving the layer, PostGIS throws the exception

> PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  column "mycolumn" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
> LINE 1: ...S (st_geomfromwkb($1::bytea,2056),$2,528,$3,$4,$5,0,'',$6) R...
> ^
> HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

However, The "0" after $5 is in the position I would expect "mycolumn" to be in. Thus, I would expect the expression to be `st_geomfromwkb($1::bytea,2056),$2,528,$3,$4,$5,$6,'',$7)`. Is this a bug and is there a workaround?

Comment: When you copied the layer to PostGIS, did you use DB Manager "Import layer/file..."? Have you tried creating a layer that contains a Boolean column without using the Processing Modeler to see if the PostGIS copy works in that case?

Comment: I didn't copy the layer, but the features in the layer by select-copy-paste. Copying from a scratch layer into a test postgis layer is working as expected (true, false and null are copied correctly)

Comment: Then 1 possible workaround is to run your model to create a layer and then use DB Manager to import the layer into your PostGIS database. That works on QGIS 3.24.1 with a Boolean column.